# Using WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration in unit tests should fail but doesn't

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

Some of our unit tests, run by MSTest, fail when accessing config properties in the tested methods. We have a config reader which uses WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/"). In unit tests it's expected that this throws an exception and we fall back to ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None). Not ideal I realise but it has worked in the past.

However, OpenWebConfiguration not only works but it returns the web.config from another project. I could almost understand if this returned the web.config from the tested project but it's just from another project in the solution.

This issue only seems to happen for me and not other devs using the same solution so I'm asking really for what settings on my machine could be causing this. I realise there are work arounds to fix this but I just want to know why this fails for me and not others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by how I'd set up my local IIS. The one website I had in there had it's physical path pointing to the folder containing the web.config that my unit tests kept loading. So for me WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/") loaded the web.config of the only website I had in IIS rather than failing as it did for other devs who had no websites in their local IIS.

So to fix this I removed the website from IIS. I realise this isn't really a good fix but this is how I got it to work for what I needed.